# Copy file from Android to Windows

Tags: java, android, windows

I wrote a small app, which creats a XML file on my Android device. No I try to copy it from my phone to my Windows PC. In Windows Explorer I can't see this file specific file, on my phone I can see this file with various file explorers. When I reboot my phone, the file appears in Windows Explorer, but I can't copy it to my desktop.

Here is my code which creates my file:

```
            String filename = "myfile.xml";
            String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+c.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

            createDir(dir);
            File file = new File(dir,filename);

            FileWriter out=null;
            try {
                String xml = createXml();
                try {

                    out =  new FileWriter(file);
                    out.write(xml);
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    out.close();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My guess is, this code doesn't free the file handle so Androids MTP cannot access this file. This would also explain, why the file is shown and could be deleted (but not able to be transfered to my PC) after rebooting my phone.

Any suggestions what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should refresh the media scanner for that file

`sendBroadcast(
    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(imageAdded))
 );`

Comment: Didn't know something like this exists. It doesn't refresh while open in Explorer, but this is enough. Thank you.